# Place an image on top of another, make gradient background colors transparent

Tags: vb.net, graphics, background, gdi+, transparent

I have 2 images, I need to put one on top of the other.
The second image is taken on a pink background (simulated below) and due to the light falloff the background is more sort of a gradient.

I need to place the image on the other one and remove the background color. I would like to define a Hue-range that represents my background, and have every pixel that falls into this range removed/being transparent so that it is pasted on top as if it had a transparent background.

This is the sample image I would like to paste on any random image:

[image: Image with gradient background]

I am able to paste the image onto another image by using this:

```
' Draw from the source to the destination.
gr.DrawImage(fr_bm, to_rect, fr_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

(image, destination rectangle, source rectangle)

But I cannot figure out how to remove the background.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, i do not care about the remaining pink pixels on the border of the object. the image will be shrunk down afterwards and will lose the details anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard Color replacement filter (simplified -> no pre [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)), since you just want to *make transparent* all pixels with colors that fall within a range).
It takes a source image, copies it to a 32Bit ARGB bitmap, then generates an identical container, used as destination bitmap.

All colors are compared to the Color specified in the `colorFrom` argument and, if the Color's components are within a threshold defined by the `tolerance` argument, the Color is replaced with the Color specified in the `colorTo` argument.

The `tolerance` value should be in the range `(1:100)` (just because Photoshop and other graphic programs do that), the `ColorReplacement` method normalizes this value on its own.

**Possible results**:
With the image in your example, with `colorFrom` set to `Color.Fucsia` and `colorTo` set to `Color.Transparent`, the green region is isolated with a tolerance of `~56`, then all remaining traces of the outer Color disappear (along with any anti-aliasing), between `80` and `90`.  After that, also the green area begins to *fade away*. Around 95, you have a completely transparent Bitmap.

With a `colorFrom` set to `(255, 226, 18, 212)`, the same results appear at `~38`, then `60` to `70` (the replacement is more *subtle*).
Which means you have to pick a source color that gives better result, in your view and context.

Try it out passing different values to the method.

**C# version**:

```
public Bitmap ColorReplacement(Bitmap image, Color colorFrom, Color colorTo, float tolerance)
{
    tolerance = (byte)(255.0f / 100.0f * Math.Max(Math.Min(100.0f, tolerance), 0.1f));
    Bitmap source = new(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    source.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(source)) {
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
        g.DrawImage(image, Point.Empty);
    }

    Bitmap destImage = new(source.Width, source.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
    foreach (PropertyItem item in image.PropertyItems) {
        source.SetPropertyItem(item);
        destImage.SetPropertyItem(item);
    }

    var dataFrom = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var dataTo = destImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, destImage.Width, destImage.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.Abs(dataTo.Stride) * dataTo.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(dataFrom.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    source.UnlockBits(dataFrom);
    int bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(source.PixelFormat) / 8;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < buffer.Length; pos += bytesPerPixel) {
        byte blue = buffer[pos];
        byte green = buffer[pos + 1];
        byte red = buffer[pos + 2];

        if ((blue < colorFrom.B + tolerance && blue > colorFrom.B - tolerance) &&
            (green < colorFrom.G + tolerance && green > colorFrom.G - tolerance) &&
            (red < colorFrom.R + tolerance && red > colorFrom.R - tolerance)) {

            int newBlue = colorFrom.B - blue + colorTo.B;
            int newGreen = colorFrom.G - green + colorTo.G;
            int newRed = colorFrom.R - red + colorTo.R;

            buffer[pos] = (byte)Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newBlue), 0);
            buffer[pos + 1] = (byte)Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newGreen), 0);
            buffer[pos + 2] = (byte)Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newRed), 0);
            buffer[pos + 3] = colorTo.A;
        }
    }
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, dataTo.Scan0, buffer.Length);
    destImage.UnlockBits(dataTo);
    return destImage;
}
```

**VB.NET version**:

```
Public Shared Function ColorReplacement(imageSource As Bitmap, colorFrom As Color, colorTo As Color, tolerance As Single) As Bitmap
    tolerance = CByte(255.0F / 100.0F * Math.Max(Math.Min(100.0F, tolerance), 0.1F))

    Dim source As New Bitmap(imageSource.Width, imageSource.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    source.SetResolution(imageSource.HorizontalResolution, imageSource.VerticalResolution)
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(source)
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half
        g.DrawImage(imageSource, Point.Empty)
    End Using

    Dim destImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    destImage.SetResolution(imageSource.HorizontalResolution, imageSource.VerticalResolution)
    For Each item As PropertyItem In imageSource.PropertyItems
        source.SetPropertyItem(item)
        destImage.SetPropertyItem(item)
    Next

    Dim dataFrom = source.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Dim dataTo = destImage.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, destImage.Width, destImage.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(Math.Abs(dataFrom.Stride) * dataFrom.Height - 1) {}
    Marshal.Copy(dataFrom.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

    source.UnlockBits(dataFrom)
    Dim bytesPerPixel As Integer = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(source.PixelFormat) \ 8

    For pos As Integer = 0 To buffer.Length - 1 Step bytesPerPixel
        Dim blue As Integer = buffer(pos)
        Dim green As Integer = buffer(pos + 1)
        Dim red As Integer = buffer(pos + 2)

        If (blue < colorFrom.B + tolerance AndAlso blue > colorFrom.B - tolerance) AndAlso
            (green < colorFrom.G + tolerance AndAlso green > colorFrom.G - tolerance) AndAlso
            (red < colorFrom.R + tolerance AndAlso red > colorFrom.R - tolerance) Then

            Dim newBlue As Integer = colorFrom.B - blue + colorTo.B
            Dim newGreen As Integer = colorFrom.G - green + colorTo.G
            Dim newRed As Integer = colorFrom.R - red + colorTo.R

            buffer(pos) = CByte(Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newBlue), 0))
            buffer(pos + 1) = CByte(Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newGreen), 0))
            buffer(pos + 2) = CByte(Math.Max(Math.Min(255, newRed), 0))
            buffer(pos + 3) = colorTo.A
        End If
    Next
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, dataTo.Scan0, buffer.Length)
    destImage.UnlockBits(dataTo)
    Return destImage
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didnt have a chance to test it before today. I tested it, it works, thank you. Would this approach also work with HSL instead of RGB? defining a hue with a offset would be easier than using RGB channels as it would ignore lightness and saturation...

Comment: You can choose whatever color space you prefer. You could pick LAB for that matter and analyze the colors based on different criteria. Colors are defined by a BGRA vector, though, you'd have to recalculate the corresponding HSL values. Not a problem, just somewhat slower. It all depends on what color reference you prefer or need to consider.  This wasn't part of the question, though. You may want to post another, preferably explaining why you'd want to consider the HSL color space (when the colors are already expressed in BGRA)